# Why is this code not working in a new file?

Tags: php, function, encoding, include, fsockopen

I have written/found a php script and I don't understand why it's working one time and the other time it doesn't. The script connects to a game server and tries to get information from it:

```
$ip = 'MyServer'; 
$port = 'OurPort';
$connect_ip = "udp://" . $ip; 
$connect = fsockopen($connect_ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);      
socket_set_timeout ($connect, 1, 000000);       
$send = "ÿÿÿÿ" . chr (0x02) . "getstatus";  
fputs($connect, $send);         
fwrite ($connect, $send);       
$output = fread($connect, 1); 
if(!empty($output)) { 
    do { 
        $status_pre = socket_get_status($connect);
        $output = $output . fread($connect, 1); 
        $status_post = socket_get_status($connect); 
    } while ($status_pre['unread_bytes'] != $status_post['unread_bytes']); 
}; 
$output = explode ('\\', $output); 

var_dump($output);
```

The output is working, something like:

```
array(149) { [0]=> string(20) "ÿÿÿÿstatusResponse " [1]=> ........ }
```

I thought: Let's do it properly and wrap it into a function like this (all code stays the same, except the beginning and end line). This will still work as long is it stays in the same file. But I thought I could put the function "check" into a new file, then I get this result:

```
**status.php**
function check($ip, $port) {

$connect_ip = "udp://" . $ip; 
$connect = fsockopen($connect_ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);      
socket_set_timeout ($connect, 1, 000000);       
$send = "ÿÿÿÿ" . chr (0x02) . "getstatus";  
fputs($connect, $send);         
fwrite ($connect, $send);       
$output = fread($connect, 1); 
if(!empty($output)) { 
    do { 
        $status_pre = socket_get_status($connect);
        $output = $output . fread($connect, 1); 
        $status_post = socket_get_status($connect); 
    } while ($status_pre['unread_bytes'] != $status_post['unread_bytes']); 
}; 
$output = explode ('\\', $output); 

var_dump($output);

}


**index.php**
include('status.php');
check('MyServer', 'OurPort')
```

But guess what? The output is now:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "ÿÿÿÿdisconnectÿÿÿÿdisconnect" }
```

How is that even possible? What am I overseeing here? Is it an encoding problem with the strange y's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using fwrite and then fputs which is an alias of fwrite so your calling fwrite twice. use it once and you wont get twice the output.

Make sure you save the file in the correct encoding. Try utf-8.

Comment: You are right, when I pass 'ÿÿÿÿ' as argument when I call the function, then it works again: check('ÿÿÿÿ', $ip, $port). But I still don't understand why. Is there an explanation for this? It has to be an encoding problem somehow...

Comment: The fputs wasn't the issue, but thx! I overread that... The issue is about the encoding. But I consider this issue as resolved as it definitely is an encoding problem.

Answer (score 1):

Those strange y's with umlauts are non-ascii characters:

```
$send = "ÿÿÿÿ" . chr (0x02) . "getstatus";
```

So if you edit such a file you have to be carefull that those are written with the correct encoding. So if the original-file is written with `iso-8859-1` then then you have to make sure that your `status.php` is also writen with `iso-8859-1` and not, for example, `utf-8`.

The better solution is to encode that "prefix" with `chr` like you did with the `chr(0x02)`. That way you ensure that your editor doesn't mix stuff up.